# SQL: Выбрать not null столбцы

Tags: sql

Например есть таблица с одной записью состоящая из столбцов 1,2,3,4. В столбцах 1,3 есть значения, в столбцах 2,4 значение null. Каким запросом возвратить таблицу содержащую только not null столбцы(1,3 в данном случае)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если известно, что таких столбца всегда два, то можно сделать так:

```
select coalesce(a1,a2,a3,a4), coalesce(a4,a3,a2,a1) from tn
```

В противном случае, боюсь, придется использовать динамический SQL.